# Magento custom attribute over the REST API

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I tried to get full list of order item attributes by this url: api/rest/orders/25/items . There are:

```
    "item_id": "62",
    "parent_item_id": null,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "sku": "89110065",
    "name": "Diamond Glow Nourishing Mud Mask",
    "qty_canceled": "0.0000",
    "qty_invoiced": "0.0000",
    "qty_ordered": "1.0000",
    "qty_refunded": "0.0000",
    "qty_shipped": "0.0000",
    "price": "277.3100",
    "base_price": "277.3100",
    "original_price": "330.0000",
    "base_original_price": "330.0000",
    "tax_percent": "19.0000",
    "tax_amount": "52.6900",
    "base_tax_amount": "52.6900",
    "discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "base_discount_amount": "0.0000",
    "row_total": "277.3100",
    "base_row_total": "277.3100",
    "price_incl_tax": "330.0000",
    "base_price_incl_tax": "330.0000",
    "row_total_incl_tax": "330.0000",
    "base_row_total_incl_tax": "330.0000"
```

If you look at the order item object, you will see that it has more attributes. Is it possible to add a custom attribute to this list? Or I have to overwrite the existing API to add a custom attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attributes you see there are defined in `api2.xml` file of the sales module.
[Here they are](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/api2.xml#L178)
This `api2.xml` works like any other XML in magento. It is merged with all the other `api2.xml` files in all the modules.
So In order to add your own attributes you can  create your own module that contains the file `etc/api2.xml` where you can add your attributes, but keep the tag structure.

Your `etc/api2.xml` could look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api2>
        <resources>
            <order_item>
                <attributes>
                    <attr_one_code_here>Attr One Label</attr_one_code_here>
                    <attr_two_code_here>Attr Two Label</attr_two_code_here>
                </attributes>
            </order_item>
        </resources>    
    </api2>
</config>
```

Clear the cache when you are done.
You may need to give access to the new attributes in the api user roles section, but not sure.

Comment: I tried it. It started to work only when I set attribute rules for Admin Role to "All". When I had checked manually all options, custom attributes didn't work.