# How to expose a custom field from sales_order table to rest api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have a custom field `delivery_type` in `sales_order` table. I am accessing order using rest api but this field is not present in response.

Requested api: `http://localhost/default/rest/default/V1/orders/2`

As suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180149/9169) I have added `etc/api2.xml` with following content in a custom module but it is not making any difference to order response.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api2>
        <resources>
            <order>
                <attributes>
                    <delivery_type>Delivery Type</delivery_type>
                </attributes>
            </order>
        </resources>
    </api2>
</config>
```

***Edit:*** If I add this attribute in `extension_attributes.xml` and `sales_order_load_after` event as mentioned [here](https://magehit.com/blog/how-to-get-value-of-custom-attribute-on-magento-2-rest-api/) I'm able to get this when I load a single order at `rest/default/V1/orders/2` but this attribute is not visible in order collection at `/rest/default/V1/orders?<search_criteria_here>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to get it working as Prince suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/236380/9169) for individual order. Though if you want to show this attribute in order collection as well you have to modify `getList` method also. Here is the complete solution:

**etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="delivery_type" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**etc/webapi_rest/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="orderInformationUpdate" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Api\OrderRepository" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin/Api/OrderRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;


class OrderRepository
{

    const DELIVERY_TYPE = 'delivery_type';

    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Add "delivery_type" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderInterface $order
     *
     * @return OrderInterface
     */
    public function afterGet(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $deliveryType = $order->getData(self::DELIVERY_TYPE);
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setDeliveryType($deliveryType);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $order;
    }

    /**
     * Add "delivery_type" extension attribute to order data object to make it accessible in API data
     *
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult
     *
     * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
     */
    public function afterGetList(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderSearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $orders = $searchResult->getItems();

        foreach ($orders as &$order) {
            $deliveryType = $order->getData(self::DELIVERY_TYPE);
            $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setDeliveryType($deliveryType);
            $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me! Thx

Comment: Thx.. @amitshree

Comment: Perfect answer...!!!

Comment: Awesome !!!! You're Great !!!!!!!!! THX !!!!!!!

It should be api to Api (first letter captital 'A')
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\api;
to 
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Api;

Answer (score 11):

In Magento 2 every API depends on Interface and output of API depends on another interface

in vendor/magento/module-sales/Api/OrderRepositoryInterface.php you can see have a method get which return \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface when you open that file has a method getExtensionAttributes() if that method available then you can add your any attribute in API. So explain step by step

Step 1: You need to create a file in your custom module app/code/Auriga/Addon/etc/extension_attributes.xml (you can implement in your any module)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="custom_attribute" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Step 2: need to create a file in app/code/Auriga/Addon/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="orderInformationUpdate" type="Auriga\Addon\Plugin\Api\OrderRepository" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 3:as declared in di.xml we need to create a file in OrderRepository.php in /var/www/html/choppingboard/app/code/Auriga/Addon/Plugin/Api/OrderRepository.php

```
<?php namespace Auriga\Addon\Plugin\Api; class OrderRepository {

public function __construct(\Auriga\Addon\Model\CartCalculation $cartCalculation) {
    $this->cartCalculation = $cartCalculation;
}

public function afterGet(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, $entity) {

    $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes ();

    
    if ($extensionAttributes) {
        $extensionAttributes->setCustomAttribute ( 'custom_value' );
        $entity->setExtensionAttributes ( $extensionAttributes );
    }
    return $entity;
}}
```

Step 4 : need to run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

And you can check a customer_attribute node is avablible in result Now open BASE_URL/rest/default/V1/orders/2

[image]

Comment: Hi Prince, it's visible when I load a particular order but not visible when I load the order collection using search criteria. Please check question edit.

Comment: Hi amitshree, that's correct its working or not. Can you send complete URL of search order collection and I have a query may be you know about how can version control of API in Magento 2

Comment: Hi Prince, I have added the solution. Please check my answer. I had to extend getList  method for order collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the attribute to this file in your extension (**extension_attributes.xml**)

after that you have to **sales_order_load_order_attribute** event to set the attribute value

there is an article with more details in this blog

https://www.wikicoode.com/magento2/add-order-attribute-custom-attributes-magento-2-rest-api

Comment: I have followed that process. Extension attribute is visible when I load one order but when I load order collection that attribute is not visible. Do you know how I can make it visible in order collection?