# Magento 2 How to get Custom Attribute Value Of Order Using Rest API

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api, sales

I have created one attribute for order named "custom_fee" and it is showing okay in magento orders frontend as well  as backend but when I tries to access order data
with rest API , I am not able to see my custom fee.

Can you please someone suggest me how I can get order custom attributes using rest API.

Here is the url that I am using for get order details

> -- [http://127.0.0.1/magento240/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria[currentPage]=0&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=000000005](http://127.0.0.1/magento240/rest/default/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5BcurrentPage%5D=0&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=000000005)

Comment: Has the order attribute been added to the api call through or as an extension attribute?

Comment: i have use extension attrbute  for order attributes

Comment: Did you write the after plugins for the order repository's get and get list methods in your module to add the data?

Comment: no i try to set using sales_order_load_after event and set extension attribute value of order

Comment: Hey @MarkRees thank you so much i got my custom fee in order details with rest api using after plugin...!!!

Comment: Hey @MarkRees i got my fee in rest api but i am not able to place order

Comment: Put the plugin code in the question

Comment: Check this link ...https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235947/how-to-expose-a-custom-field-from-sales-order-table-to-rest-api